# Does boto support for 'hit visibility'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

When creating hits, Amazon turk's requester interface allows to set visibility for hits (. For example, all Workers can see my HITs, but only Workers that meet all Qualification requirements can preview my HITs.

Can boto make this setting when creating hits? Is there anyone that can let me know this?

Comment: If you cannot find an answer for boto1/boto2, go checkout boto3
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.create_hit

Comment: Thanks for the link very much. I did check the reference but it seems that there is not a parameter in 'create_hit' to allow visibility setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few layers to this. If you want to limit the Workers that can preview the HIT, it's a configuration parameter of the QualificationRequirement, which is a data structure you attach to the HIT when you call CreateHIT or CreateHITType. You can see an example of this in action with Boto here: https://github.com/awslabs/mturk-code-samples/blob/master/Python/CreateHitSample.py

Specifically, the section:

```
localRequirements = [{
    'QualificationTypeId': '00000000000000000071',
    'Comparator': 'In',
    'LocaleValues': [{
        'Country': 'US'
    }, {
        'Country': 'CA'
    }],
    'RequiredToPreview': True
}]

# Create the HIT 
response = client.create_hit(
    MaxAssignments = 10,
    LifetimeInSeconds = 600,
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds = 600,
    Reward ='0.20',
    Title = 'Answer a simple question',
    Keywords = 'question, answer, research',
    Description = 'Answer a simple question',
    Question = questionSample,
    QualificationRequirements = localRequirements
)
```

If you want to go a step further and make HITs entirely hidden from Workers if they aren't qualified (or use a Premium Qualification), you can only do that from the Requester Website. But there's a way to create a HIT Type in the Requester Website then access it with the SDK (including Boto). You do that like this:

1) Create the HIT Type in the Requester Website. You can follow this tutorial: https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-how-to-quickly-create-hits-using-our-ruby-sdk-and-hit-editor-ffa83593dbf5

2) Get access to the HIT Type ID, HIT Layout ID, and HIT Layout Parameters as shown in that blog post. Specifically, you want to log into the Requester Website, click Create, then click on the name of the Template that you created. A small modal will come up that looks like this:

[image]

3) Then, use code like this to create the HIT. For full disclosure, this is using Boto3 (while the blog above was written before support for MTurk in Boto3 existed; sorry for any confusion from mixing and matching):

```
client.create_hit_with_hit_type(HITTypeId = "3UTQDPKCBDPS43G3N3YCFJLHPDX514",
                                HITLayoutId = "3ASV3OFR42CJPPALP03SPQPR0GRDYI",
                                HITLayoutParameters = [{ 'Name': 'image_url', 'Value':'http://example.com/image.png'}, 
                                                       { 'Name': 'objects_to_find', 'Value': 'example object' }],
                                LifetimeInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3)
```

Because you're just using the HIT Type created using the Requester Website, it'll use all the same properties and attributes of that HIT Type, including the visibility parameters (and any Premium Qualifications).

Hope that's helpful. Good luck with it!

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this detailed answer. It really is a good solution to specifying visibility in sdk. But in this case (using HITTypeId and HITLayoutId), I cannot use ExternalQuestion any more. Because I am using question = questionform to integrate an external website in the turk frame, creat_hit with hittype doesn't allow me to do this any more. Do you have idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If you're just trying to stop folks from preview, you can do that in the SDK/API now. Are you trying to make the HITs entirely hidden (e.g., won't even show up when a Worker searches for them) or are you ok with having them appear, but Workers not being able to preview? If the latter, then the first code sample above should work.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. What I need is the former one, i.e., making the hits entirely hidden, even won't show up when a worker searches for them. Is there any way to realize this through API?

Comment: The only way to do this is to create your HIT Type with the Requester Website (http://requester.mturk.com/) and then use that HIT Type ID in the API using create_hit_with_hit_type.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I am now clear. Then there is no way to set the visibility in an external-question based hit. Thanks again!!